# jquery window.load() function won't trigger on ios5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple loading div on my page that fades out when the whole page has been loaded.
I am using a simple code snippet as follows :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#loading').fadeOut(500);
});
```

this code is working fine in all my desktop browsers and in my mobiles chrome, but it won't work with my ipod 3g's ios5 safari browser.The loader won't go away thus the webpage is useless.
What can I do to solve this problem?
ps: I don't want to use `document.ready` here because what I'm trying to do happens when the page has been COMPLETELY loaded.

Comment: From my experience you can not rely on anything else as document.ready on iOS other than to inject the Markup via JS and monitor image loading by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out by myself that using javascript's native `load` event will solve the problem :

```
window.addEventListner('load', function(){
    //do the stuff
});
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#loading').fadeOut(500);
});
```